# External package (JS/CSS) are loaded properly on IE and Chrome, but not on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am testing a page which I programmed based on jquery and external package(qtip and fancybox). 
But I don't know why it is not working on firefox, but works on IE and Chrome.

Here is the screenshots. 
Firefox:

[image]

Chrome: 
[image]

IE: 
[image]

Comment: Status 407 is proxy authentication needed. It seems that your proxy settings are wrong in FF

Comment: @MatildaYiPan To mark your question as solved, do not edit it; add your answer as an answer to the question, using the below text area.  Then select the answer by clicking the check mark outline.

Comment: @Daedalus I have already added my solution as an answer, but I cannot mark it to accept. The tick symbol doesn't work at the moment, it says "you can accept this answer in 2 days". Maybe there is a timeline for it.

Comment: @MatildaYiPan There is a time limit, yes, but that's how you mark your question as solved in this system; by adding a solution and marking it.

Comment: @Daedalus I learnt from it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved. My office is under a proxy, so in FF - options- Advanced - Network - Connection - Settings, changes the settings to " Auto-detect", and the external package will be loaded properly. Thank you.